# Simple JSON example using Struts 2.2.x?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, struts2

I’m having trouble getting JSON results working with [Struts 2.2.1.1](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/index.html).

Does anyone have a simple working example that returns a JSON result to a JSP using *Struts 2.2.1.1* and is ready to run in **Eclipse** as a *dynamic web project*?

Please include the struts.xml, action class and JSP code. Also, note dependencies. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s how to create a simple JSON example using the Struts 2 jQuery plugin.

1. Go to [Struts2 jQuery Plugin Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)
2. Navigate to **Ajax Forms > Buttonset / Checkboxes**
3. Review the code for *Buttonset that was populated from AJAX JSON Result*. This is code I selected to create a simple example.
4. Create dynamic web project in Eclipse
5. Create a Java package and name it *test*.
6. Download the [Struts 2 jQuery plugin showcase source](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list) (*struts2-jquery-showcase-x.x.x-sources.jar*) and extract the JAR file.
7. Import `Echo.java`, `JsonSample.java`, and `ListValue.java` into the *test* package and move the code into the package with quick fix.
8. Change the class annotation in `Echo.java` and `JsonSample.java` to @`ParentPackage(value = "test")`
9. In addition to the standard Struts 2 libraries, ensure that the *struts2-json-plugin-x.x.x.jar*, *struts2-jquery-plugin-x.x.x.jar*, and *struts2-convention-plugin-x.x.x.jar* files are in your classpath.
10. Create a `struts.xml` file and add the following XML:

    ```
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="test" />
        <package name="test" extends="json-default” namespace="/">
        </package>
    </struts>
    ```
11. Create an index.jsp file and insert the following code:

    ```
    <s:form id="form2" action="echo" theme="xhtml">
     <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonsample" />
    <sj:checkboxlist href="%{remoteurl}" id=“remoteCheckboxlist” name="echo"  list="languageList" label="Language" />
    <sj:submit targets="formResult" value="AJAX Submit" indicator=“indicator” button="true"/>
    </s:form>
    ```
12. Run the example.

Comment: I have followed all above steps..but i got these exception:  "Status 404 - /testSamples/index.jsp".. can u plz help me?

Comment: @johnnieb - Your link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

**Must see** : struts2-x.x.x-all.zip /apps/struts2-showcase-2.2.1.war

[Struts 2 and JSON example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)
[Struts 2 autocompleter + JSON example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-autocompleter-json-example/)

Comment: The showcase has no examples. The link examples are packaged as Maven projects. We’re an Ant shop and I can’t get the files to run properly in Eclipse. I’d prefer to have a ZIP archive that’s ready to be imported into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to get Json work with struts2.

For this,

1. you need to add struts-json plugin**(jsonplugin-0.32.jar)** to classpath.
2. Your struts.xml file should extends **json-default**

   ```
   <package name="base" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
   ```
3. Your action result be like this.

   ```
   <result type="json"><param name="root">jsonData</param></result>
   ```
4. Inside action class, declare json as

`private LinkedHashMap<K, V> jsonData new LinkedHashMap<k, V>();`

and then add the result list to json like

```
jsonData.put("result", anyList or object);
```

Thats all we have to do. Then we can access the **result** using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will help you in Struts 2.0.14 with jsonplugin-0.32.jar.

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
     <package name="example" extends="json-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
              <action name="HelloWorld1" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result name="success" >example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

action class Helloworld.java:

```
package prabhakar;

import glb.DB;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Prabhakar
 */
public class HelloWorld  {


    private List<StateMaster> stateList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();
    private List<RegnMaster> regnList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();

    private Integer stateId;
    public Integer getStateId()
    {
    return this.stateId;
    }
    public void setStateId(Integer stateId)
    {
    this.stateId=stateId;
    }
    public List<StateMaster> getStateList() {
        return stateList;
    }

    public void setStateList(List<StateMaster> stateList) {
        this.stateList = stateList;
    }
     public void setRegnList(List<RegnMaster> regnList) {
        this.regnList = regnList;
    }
    public List<RegnMaster> getRegnList() {
        return regnList;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        stateList=DB.getStateData()//
        if(stateId !=null)
          {
         regnList=DB.getRegnByStateId(stateId);
          }

        //setMessage(getText(MESSAGE));
        return "success";
    }

    /**
     * Provide default valuie for Message property.
     */

}
```

You can directly call HelloWorld.action to view the JSON data or else you can bind the JSON data to a form element below.

JSP page HelloWorld.jsp:

```
  /*
     Prabhakar
  */

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<script>
<%@include file="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%>
</script>
    <html>

<!-- JavaScript Plugins -->
  <script>
       function getLoad(){


       var stateId = $('#state').val();

$.getJSON('HelloWorld.action', {'stateId': stateId},
    function(data) {

           var divisionList = (data.regnList);

                var options = $("#regn");
                options.find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();
     options.append($("<option />").val("-1").text("--Select--"));
$.each(divisionList, function() {

    options.append($("<option />").val(this.regnId).text(this.regnName));
});
    }
);}
   </script>

<!-- jQuery-UI Dependent Scripts -->

    <body>
        State List <s:select name="stateId" list="stateList" id="state" listKey="stateId" onchange="getLoad()" listValue="stateName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
        Regn List <s:select name="regnId"  list="regnList" listKey="regnId" id="regn" listValue="regnName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Happy coding :)